# How to run make file from any directory?

Tags: make, makefile

In order to run make file, I am supposed to go to the make file's directory and from there only I can run the make file. How can I do the same even if i am in any directory?

Comment: Which `make`?  Borland's `make`?  GNU `make`?  Microsoft's `nmake`?  One of the umpteen shareware implementations of `make` that have floated around over the years?  And on what platform?  The answer is different depending from the specifics.  `RedGrittyBrick` is presuming that you have a POSIX-conformant shell and filesystem, for example.

Comment: do `make -C dir`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

#### General solution

```
(cd /other/dir && make)
```

will not change *your shell's* current directory (because the brackets contents are run in a subshell), but will run `make` with the indicated working directory.

The `&&` will ensure that `make` doesn't run if there's an error in the `cd` part of the command (e.g., the directory doesn't exist, or you don't have access to it).

The above approach is useful for all sorts of commands, not just `make`. For this reason it is worth learning and remembering.

#### Specific solution

Check the man page for a `-C` option, e.g.

```
make -C /other/dir
```

Several Unix commands started out without this option but had it added to them at some time (e.g. with GNU implementation)

Comment: Looks like there's a `-C` option to make for most Unixes these days. Details and some more complete answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/453447/357774

Comment: why will that not change the directory?

Comment: @CharlieParker the brackets `()` causes the command to be run in a subshell, changes to current-working-directory made in the subshell do not affect the parent shell. When the command finishes, the subshell exits and control returns to the parent shell. I've updated this (11-year old) answer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 59):

You could use

```bsh
make -C dir
```

to change to directory `dir` before reading the pointed makefile. Please notice that option `-C` is capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I like to use a `~/.bashrc` alias, which looks like this:

```bsh
alias makeaway="cd /dir/to/make && make && cd -"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cd ./dir && make && pwd` inside Makefile .

Example of sample Makefile :

```
BUILD_DIR       =       $(shell pwd)

deploy::
        cd ./dist/local && make && pwd && npm publish && cd .. && cd .. && pwd
clean::
        npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: The && was exactly what I needed to change a directory and execute a command there, then drop back to the main folder to finish the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it with Makefile targets.

```
make {your target} -C {your Makefile directory}
```

For instance:

```
make flcean -C /home/yourlogin/yourdirectory
```

Comment: Same answer has been provided more than 12 years ago.