# How to run "make" command on a "empty directory"?

Tags: command-line, msys2

I'm attempting to install something, and the instructions for installation say I have to use MSYS2 to use make on a certain directory to make a .exe file in my C drive. 
This directory exists: I already know where it is. However, when putting in commands like `cd \MYDIRECTORY && make`, (I'm **not** familiar with the make command yet, keep that in mind...) an error appears:

`bash: cd: MYDIRECTORY: No such file or directory`. Am I typing it wrong? (I followed [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/370575/how-to-run-make-file-from-any-directory?newreg=8d9b83693c0244638df47b0f6132a4eb) to try and fix it, but I don't understand it...) If so, how can I fix it? Any correct commands I can use?

SCREENSHOT:
[The instructions on GitHub.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ1b9.png)

Any feedback relating to this question helps!

Thanks, Omega207

Comment: What is the full path to `MYDIRECTORY`?

Comment: It is C:\Users\ (USER)\AppData\Local\MYDIRECTORY.

Comment: …Wait. Do "make" commands change values only? Do I need to find some specific value to "make" my directory .exe?

Comment: Well the files you are trying to "make" have to be in the directory.

Comment: Okay, for the sake of being able to help, the files inside the directory are: a .z64 file, and a config file.

Comment: What are you trying to install? Where is it downloaded from?

Comment: I'm attempting to get Super Mario 64 Plus, a PC game. The installer asks me to put in the make command into the "MYDIRECTORY" directory.

Comment: I've no idea what your are trying to do. So it's hard to help you. Where is it downloaded from? Please provide the link.

Comment: The download is here: https://mfgg.net/index.php?act=resdb&param=02&c=2&id=38190, and the instructions are here: https://github.com/MorsGames/sm64plus/wiki/Manual-Building-Guide

Comment: You need to follow the instructions **exactly** as they are written.

Comment: Okay, I believe the problem has been solved. Turns out I needed the BaseROM copied from my original launcher folder into my SM64Plus directory on my C Drive, THEN run "make" commands. Sorry for hiding the game name -- I did not want to cause a problem using this Nintendo fangame.

Answer (score 0):

- MSYS2 basically gives you a Unix shell (namely `bash`), which is different from the Windows commandline.
- The `&&` just allows you two execute two commands in one line. Forget the `make` for the moment, concentrate on the `cd`.
- `cd \MYDIRECTORY` is expecting `MYDIRECTORY` directly under the "root" of MSYS2, which is not going to work.
- Try `cd /cygdrive/c`, if that works, then your MSYS2 uses the Cygwin conventions (that's the equivalen of typing `C:` under the Windows commandline).
- Now try `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/(USER)/AppData/Local/MYDIRECTORY`. If you have spaces in your directory name, this may not work.
- You can use `pwd` to have a look at your current directory.
- Once you are in the current directory, remember that you need a file called `Makefile` in order for the command `make` to work. If you don't have that, it won't work.
- If you already used `cd` to get into the right directory, you can just type `make` (no need for `&&`, no need for a `cd`).

Also, try working through some bash/Cygwin/MSYS2 tutorial, in order to get familiar with the commandline.